# Laravel 5.4 y Centos 7: storage/logs/laravel.log (Permission denied)

Tags: laravel-5, apache, centos, permisos, php7

Estoy usando PHP 7.1 sobre Apache y acabo de instalar un proyecto de Laravel 5.4 en Centos 7, y obtengo el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi usuario es "root", los permisos de mi directorio son los siguientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He ejecutado los siguientes comandos:

```
sudo chmod -R 644 storage
sudo chmod -R 755 storage
```

En ambos casos ocurre lo mismo. Como dato adicional, debo mencionar que durante la instalación no pude instalar el paquete ext-zip de php 7.1, no lo encontré, ¿Será eso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para todo aquel que lo necesite: El problema fue causado por algo llamado SELINUX el cual debe ser deshabilitado con el siguiente comando:

```
sudo setenforce 0
```

[Según este enlace](http://www.anjuke.tech/questions/1267236/failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied-error-laravel) este error es causado por diferentes usuarios intentando escribir sobre el mismo log de archivos con el directorio **storage/log** con diferentes permisos.

Answer (score 0):

el usuario que maneja el apache por lo general es el usuario `www-data` no el usuario `root` por ello es que te manda el error.

solucion:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data storage
sudo chmod -R 644 storage
```

Answer (score 0):

Aplicar lo siguiente:

setenforce 1

sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/var/www/proyect_name/storage(/.*)?"

sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/var/www/proyect_name/bootstrap/cache(/.*)?"

find storage -type d -exec chmod 775 {} ;

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución c: Vendría genial que explicaras lo que hace tu código tanto para el OP como para personas que vean tu respuesta en el futuro.